# Is there a way to fix the blinking of a dropdown menu over a .pdf loaded in a <div>?

Tags: 2007, ie6, internet-explorer, pdf, content-editor-web-part

I have an object inside a `<div>` that is displaying a pdf.  This is done within a Content Editor Web Part.  My drop down navigation menu "blinks" whenever it is over the `<div>`.  The drop down blinks in Internet Explorer 6 and is hidden behind the `<div>` in Chrome.  Is there any way to fix this blinking and hiding? (I have tried z-index)

```
<div style="z-index:-999">
<object data="page.pdf#navpanes=0" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="900"></object>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a low z-index inline on the object itself, and make sure your class for your li's has a higher z-index. Object's don't inherit from the parent object in the DOM, so you must specify inline on the object tag.

```
<object data="page.pdf#navpanes=0" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="900" style="z-index: 1;"></object>
```

Comment: I can't seem to get my dropdown menu items to get a z-index.  I am using the basic menu from sharepoint, and it is in a table format, I have tried making the table have a higher z-index.  Do the table elements each need a z-index?

Comment: You're probably going to have to append some CSS a tad. Find the class of the table's and table cells and write a new line of css that just elevates their z-index. You will need to make sure that the table, table rows and table cells all have a z-index higher than the object. The joys of the ugly 2007 DOM!

Comment: It worked for my first drop down, so now I need to carry it over to my other ones, thanks.